# Redirect page in asp.net in new window

Tags: asp.net, redirect, menu, html, new-window

I have a Radmenu of pages . On the menu I have 5 menu items. One of them is "user guide". Clicking this should open a new window with the page manualpage.aspx.IN this page I have a page load which should pull up my manual.pdf but keeping the previous window same

So i login into system i get systemsmenu.aspx. In that I have the radmenu on left. Clicking the item "User Guide" should open manualpage.aspx in new window and have my manual.pdf be brought up in this new window. I should STILL BE ON systemsmenu.aspx in the before or first window.
I tried

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Response.Write("<script>window.open('/myfolder/Docs/manual.pdf','_blank');</script>")
End Sub
```

What is happening now is it is opening a new window fine and my manual shows up in 2nd window but my first window URL says "..../manualpage.aspx". It should be systemsmenu.aspx. What do i do? If you need more info ,please ask. Thanks

Comment: How the "User Guide" link is populated? Is it using Javascript?

Comment: Forcing things to open in a new window is often frustrating for users, because the default is to open in the same instance. If the user wants to open it in a new window or tab, I think the best practice is to allow them to do it via context menu (right click).

Comment: @w3hunter. The user guide is a menu item in the rad menu.I have a table that brings up the menu items. In that table against this menu item i have a URL column to which it goes.

Comment: @mason. Well, the client wants it like that. Since the new page is just a plain pdf i cannot have a menu in that page. Any alternative ideas?

Comment: try adding Response.Clear();Response.End(); after Response.Write();

Comment: Or using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`, instead of writing directly to the response.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. Since it is a telerik rad control I found the "Target" property for that RadMenuItem. I am checking while creating the menu if it is "User Guide" and if it is then setting the Target property to "_blank". It worked.